# the x,y coordinates of a custom UIVIew

Tags: objective-c, uiview

How do you obtain the x,y coordinates of a custom UIVIew?

```
NSLog(@"landscape orientation and myUIView.x==%f and myUIView.y==%f",myUIView.position.x ,myUIView.position.y )
```

I get the following error

```
request for member 'position' in something not a structure or union
```

Comment: Note that all drawing is translated to the appropriate coordinate system -- if you are just trying to draw something assume the position is {0, 0}, it's bad practice to try to know about anything outside of the view itself

Answer (score 13):

UIView does not have a position property but it does have a frame property ([documented here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame)) which is a CGRect.  CGRect contains the origin (x/y coordinates) and size.

```
NSLog(@"landscape orientation and myUIView.x==%f and myUIView.y==%f",
    myUIView.frame.origin.x,
    myUIView.frame.origin.y )
```

The frame's coordinates are in the coordinate system of the parent UIView (superview).

**EDIT** I recently learned another way to print coordinates:

```
NSLog(@"myUIView origin=%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(myUIView.frame.origin));
```

or the entire CGRect:

```
NSLog(@"myUIView frame=%@", NSStringFromCGRect(myUIView.frame));
```